# Loop in subset of an array matching key text in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, transformation

I have this array (using PHP):

```
Array
(
[dummy_value_01] => 10293
[other_dummy_value_01] => Text
[top_story_check] => 1
[top_story_hp] => 1
[top_story] => 248637
[top_story_id] => 100
[top_story_text] => 2010
[menu_trend_01] => 248714
[menu_trend_01_txt] => Text 01
[menu_trend_02] => 248680
[menu_trend_02_txt] => Text 02
[menu_trend_03] => 248680
[menu_trend_03_txt] => Text 03
[menu_trend_04] => 248680
[menu_trend_04_txt] => Text 04
[menu_trend_05] => 248680
)
```

I would like to loop only the menu_trend_* values and obtain a list like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Text 01: 248714</li>
<li>Text 02: 248680</li>
<li>[...]</li>
</ul>
```

Could you suggest the best way?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that this is the best way, but it will work:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $a) {
  if (stristr($k, 'menu_trend_') && !empty($arr[$k . '_txt'])) {
    $output[] = $arr[$k . '_txt'] . ': ' . $a;
  }
}
echo "<ul>\n<li>" . implode("</li>\n<li>", $output) . "</li>\n</ul>";
```

#### [Here's a working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5SuS3w)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it will try to match menu_trend_(DIGIT) and if it does, will echo the needed text.

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {


    $matches = array();
    if (!preg_match('/^menu_trend_(\d+)$/', $key, $matches)) {

        continue;
    }

    echo sprintf('<li>Text %s: %s</li>', $matches[1], $val);
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: This returns a strage list: <ul>
<li>Text 01: 248714</li>
<li>Text 01: Text 01</li>
<li>Text 02: 248680</li>
<li>Text 02: Text 02</li>
</ul>

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to terminate the regex rule, now try it